# C++ Getting compilation error while insert string into a map

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, vector

I used `get()` and `getline()` to read the file then input to my `map()`. Then insert from map class to `AVLTree` and `AVLNode` class. What should I do to fix the const string error and where the exactly problem is? Thank you for all your time and help. Here is the whole code.
https://github.com/RichardHung/AVL-BST-Tree.git

> 60 13  SequenceMap.cpp [Error] passing 'const std::basic_string' as 'this' argument of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
>   [Note] void std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::push_back(_CharT) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator]
>   [Note] no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const std::basic_string' to 'char'

```
template <typename Comparable_1, typename Comparable_2>
class AvlNode
{
  Comparable_1 element1; // sequence
  vector<Comparable_2> element2; // enzy
  AvlNode *left;
  AvlNode *right;
  int height;
  bool exist;
  AvlNode( const Comparable_1 & theElement1, const Comparable_2 & theElement2, AvlNode *lt, AvlNode *rt, int h = 0, bool ex = false): 
  element1( theElement1 ),element2( theElement2 ), left( lt ), right( rt ), height( h ), exist( ex ) { }
  friend class AvlTree<Comparable_1, Comparable_2>;
};

template <typename Comparable_1, typename Comparable_2>
void AvlTree<Comparable_1, Comparable_2>::insert( const Comparable_1 & x, const Comparable_2 y, AvlNode<Comparable_1, Comparable_2> * & t )
{
 if( t == NULL )
     t = new AvlNode<Comparable_1, Comparable_2>( x, y, NULL, NULL, true );
 else if( x < t->element1 )
 {
      insert( x, y, t->left );
      if( height( t->left ) - height( t->right ) == 2 )
          if( x < t->left->element1 )
              rotateWithLeftChild( t );
          else
              doubleWithLeftChild( t );
 }
 else if( x > t->element1 )
 {
      insert( x, y, t->right );
      if( height( t->right ) - height( t->left ) == 2 )
          if( x < t->right->element1 )
              rotateWithRightChild( t );
          else
              doubleWithRightChild( t );
 }
 else // ( x == t->element1 )
 {
     t->element2 = y ;
 }
 t->height = max( height( t->left ), height( t->right ) ) + 1;
 }

template <typename Comparable_1, typename Comparable_2>
class SequenceMap
{
  public:
         Comparable_1 key;                      
         Comparable_2 value;            
         AvlTree < Comparable_1, Comparable_2 > avl;
         BinarySearchTree < Comparable_1, Comparable_2 > bst;
         SequenceMap(){};
         ~SequenceMap();
         }
template <typename Comparable_1, typename Comparable_2>
void SequenceMap<Comparable_1, Comparable_2>::AVLinsert( const Comparable_1 & str, const Comparable_2 & set )
{
if ( avl.isEmpty( ) )        
{
    key = str;
    value = set;
    avl.insert( key, value );
}   
else                        // check the enzy is duplicated or not
{
    for( int i=0; i<set.size( ); i++ )
    {
        if ( avl.findEnzyme( key, set ) ) // if cannot find the enzy in the node
        {
                merge( set );
                avl.insert( key, value ); 
        } 
    }  
    // if find the same enzy in the node, do nothing to avoid duplicated.
}
}
```

main.cpp

```
while ( ! fin.eof( ) )
{           
    if ( fin.peek( ) == '/' )
    {
        fin.get();      // skip "/" and move ptr to next sequence
        while ( fin.peek() != '\n' ) 
        {
            getline(fin, sequence, '/');
            cout << "enzyme: " << enzyme << endl;
            cout << "sequence: " << sequence << endl;
            map.insert(tree, sequence, enzyme);
            sequence.clear();
            fin.get();  // skip "/" and move ptr to next sequence
            if(fin.peek() == '/')
                fin.get();                  
        }
        fin.get();
        enzyme.clear();
    }
    else // if( enz != '/' )
    {
        enzyme += fin.get( );
    }

}
```

Comment: Without knowing what `SequenceMap` is theres not much we can do.

Comment: A std::map is likely a tree (AVL, Red/Black, ...)

Comment: @DieterLücking I thought is tree like a sorting algorithm and map is a data storing as a node with key(element_1) and value(element_2)?

Comment: @Richard Are you passing three strings into that `insert` call?

Comment: @caps when I pass to map, the 1st parameter is a const str "AVL". 2nd expect to be string but it gives me a vector<string>. 3rd is string. then map would store the str into vector so the tree would have vector as 2nd datatype.

Comment: @Richard we can't help you without knowing more about the definition of the `SequenceMap`.

Comment: @caps My bad. I pass the std::string as reference from main to map then to the tree class. Then it change to const when it pass to node class. the c++ lib use vector<template>::push_back(std::char) What should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: @Borgleader Sorry my bad.Can you take a look on what make the std::string pass as const std::string? How should I fix it as std::string pass as std::string?

Comment: One of your edits took out the `map` declaration, along with a bunch of other variable declarations. I had to look at the edit history to see exactly what it was.

Comment: @caps You mean the map's member declaration or function declaration?
`template <typename Comparable_1, typename Comparable_2>
class SequenceMap
{
  public:
         Comparable_1 key;                      
         Comparable_2 value;            
         AvlTree < Comparable_1, Comparable_2 > avl;
         BinarySearchTree < Comparable_1, Comparable_2 > bst;
         SequenceMap(){};
         ~SequenceMap();
         }`

Comment: I think I solved your problem. See my answer. In the future I suggest that you learn how to make a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://www.sscce.org/). Many times just the process of doing so will show you what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pay attention to your compiler warnings.

In a couple of your classes you had `std::vector<Comparable_2>` members where I think you meant to have just plain old `Comparable_2` members. I couldn't get your code to compile without changing that. As far as I can tell, that was your main issue. You can't just assign an object of type `T` to a container of type `vector<T>`. Not only are they different types with no implicit conversions according to the compiler, but such an assignment makes no logical sense.

You may have meant to use a `std::vector<Comparable_2>`. In that case your syntax is wrong in numerous places; you will need to do things like `element2.push_back(y)` instead of `element2 = y`. You'll also need to change your comparisons like `element2 == y` to something like `std::find(element2.begin(), element2.end(), y) != element2.end()`, because just like you can't assign a `T` to a `vector<T>`, you also won't be able to compare a `T` to a `vector<T>`.

However, you had quite a few significant compiler warnings: ambiguous `if/else` blocks, many functions not always returning a value, other functions never ever returning a value, etc. If changing your `element2` members from `std::vectors` to `std::strings` still doesn't let your code compile, I'd have a look at fixing some of those warnings--several of them will probably lead to your app doing things you don't expect.

[Here is a link to coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7666cb243c0cdcf) compiling and running your app. I loaded the input file into this [other coliru instance here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e39b9c8d616ffd4).

As a side note, you really [shouldn't do `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453605/2025214).

Comment: So is that means avoid using vector here?

Comment: Thanks. I stop using vector to make the code simple. I will post the code after I finish it.
The reason I use vector is that I think I can make it expendable if I want to insert something more.

Comment: You could still use vector, but you would have to change the syntax and logic to reflect such a change. The syntax and logic you currently have presumes the object is just a `Comparable_2`